# How to get HideShow to indicate Flycheck Errors/Warnings inside a folded region?

Tags: flycheck

When a portion of code is folded, error and warning indicators from Flycheck relative to this portion are not shown.

How can I get Flycheck or HideShow to indicate that a folded portion of code contains errors/warnings ?